# Is there a well known proof that shows solutions of $y^2=3x^4+1$ are only (1,2), (2,7) over positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I found a theorem from a book 'Diophantine equations', L. J. Mordell, which says

The equation $y^2 = Dx^4+1$
where $D>0$ and is not a perfect square, has at most two solutions in positive integers.

But I can't find any proof in this book, and I tried to find its proof but I failed.
Is there anybody knows its proof?

Comment: Maybe $(y-1)(y+1) = 3x^4$ will help you

Comment: I think that you will find quite fast that for any prime factor other than 2 you will find great difficulty gathering up 4 factors together on $y-1$ and $y+1$.

Comment: Do you want to prove it for every $D>0$ or just for $D=3$ ?

Comment: It's better to prove it for every D, but I don't care if I can prove it just for D=3.

Comment: Not a proof, but "u=quadunit(4*3);for(j=1,10^5,s=component(u^j,3);if(issquare(s)==1,print(j,"  ",s)))" checks the first $10^5$ solutions of the Pell-equation $y^2-3x^2=1$ whether $x$ is a perfect square quite quickly in PARI/GP. The output shows only the solutions $1$ and $4$ corresponding to the solutions you mentioned. Looking at the square root of the final value of $s$ reveals that another $x$ must have more than $28\ 000$ digits. Maybe using the structure of the solutions allows even to complete the proof.

Comment: Try googling "x^2-dy^4=1".

Comment: I already did. It was quite useless.

Comment: By googling "x^2-dy^4=1", I found at least four pages...

Comment: I was idiot. I tried to google 'y^2-dx^4=1' all day, and I couldn't get anything. Thank you for advice.

Comment: But I still can't find proof of W. Ljunggren...

Answer (score 1):

$y^2 = 3x^4+1\tag{1}$
Using online Magma calculator as follows.
IntegralQuarticPoints($[3,0,0,0,1]$);

It says that all integral points are $( ( 0, 1 ), ( 1, 2 ), ( -1, 2 ), ( 2, 7 ), ( -2, 7 ))$.
Hence all positive integral points are $(x,y)=(1,2),(2,7).$

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2 = Dx^4+1\implies x = ± \frac{\sqrt[4]{y^2 - 1}}{\sqrt[4]{D}}\implies x^4=\frac{y^2-1}{D}\quad x,y\in\mathbb{N}$$

We can see that $y^2-1$ must be a $0$ or multiple of $(D)$ and $(y^2-1)/D$ must also be a $4^{th}$ power integer. Simple spreadsheet formulas reveal $(D,x,y)$ values as shown in these samples where $(D,0,1)$ is valid for all values of $D$ but omitted here for brevity.

$$
(3,1,2)\quad (3,2,7)\quad (5,2,9)\quad (8,1,3)\quad (14,2,15)\quad (15,1,4)\quad (18,2,17)\quad (24,1,5)\quad (33,2,23)\quad (35,1,6)\quad (39,2,25)\quad (48,1,7)\quad (60,2,31)\quad (63,1,8)\quad (68,2,33)\quad (80,1,9)\quad (99,1,10)\quad ...
$$

Comment: This is not a proof, nor does it answer the question.